# Why is decimal more precise than double if it has a shorter range? C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, decimal

Im reading the C# in a Nutshell book and it shows this table:
[image]

Im having a hard time understanding the table. It says that double takes `64 bits` of space and it ranges from `10^-324` to `10^308`.
Decimal takes `128 bits` of space BUT is also says that it ranges from `10^-28` to `10^28`. So what im understanding here is that decimal takes more space but provides a shorter range? this doesnt make much sense in my head since everyone agrees that decimal should be use when precision is required. 
Also when doing a calculation like = `(1/3)*3`, the desire result is `1`, but only `float` and `double` give me `1`, `decimal` gives me `0.9999`... So why is `decimal` more precise? I dont really understand.

Comment: Roughly speaking, more digits to the right of the decimal point means more precision. The more digits you track on the right of the decimal point, the less you can have on the left of the decimal point. Both sides of the decimal point need to fit into 128 bits (in the case of a decimal).

Comment: Its precision is not greater but __different__. It can store decimal digits precisely and as you are used to consider these the true values it seems to be more precise. If you were used to binary numbers, double would be.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> what I'm understanding here is that decimal takes more space but provides a shorter range?

Correct. It provides higher precision and smaller range. Plainly if you have a limited number of bits, you can increase precision only by decreasing range!

> everyone agrees that decimal should be use when precision is required

Since that statement is false -- in particular, I do not agree with it -- any conclusion you draw from it is not sound.

The purpose of using decimal is not higher precision. It is *smaller representation error*.  Higher precision is one way to achieve smaller representation error, but decimal does not achieve its smaller representation error by being higher precision. It achieves its smaller representation error by *exactly representing decimal fractions*.

Decimal is for those scenarios where the representation error of a decimal fraction must be *zero*, such as a financial computation.

> Also when doing a calculation like = (1/3)*3, the desire result is 1, but only float and double give me 1

You got lucky. There are lots of fractions where the representation error of that computation is non-zero for both floats and doubles.

Let's do a quick check to see how many there are. We'll just make a million rationals and see:

```
    var q = from x in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
            from y in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
            where ((double)x)/y*y != x
            select x + " " + y;
    Console.WriteLine(q.Count()); // 101791
```

**Over 10% of all small-number rationals are represented as doubles with sufficiently large representation error that they do not turn back into whole numbers when multiplied by their denominator!**

If your desire is to do exact arithmetic on arbitrary rationals then neither double nor decimal are the appropriate type to use.  **Use a big-rational library if you need to exactly represent rationals.**

> why is decimal more precise?

Decimal is more precise than double because it has more bits of precision.

But again, precision is not actually that relevant. What is relevant is that decimal has smaller *representation error* than double for many common fractions.

It has smaller representation error than double for representing fractions with a small power of ten in the denominator because it was *designed specifically* to have zero representation error for all fractions with a small power of ten in the denominator.

That's why it is called "decimal", because it represents *fractions with powers of ten*. It represents the *decimal system*, which is the system we commonly use for arithmetic.

Double, in contrast, was explicitly not designed to have small representation error.  **Double was designed to have the range, precision, representation error and performance that is appropriate for physics computations.**

There is no bias towards exact decimal quantities in physics. There is such a bias in finance.  **Use decimals for finance. Use doubles for physics.**

Comment: is what you've written comes under basic arithmetics, bc I certainly can't understand all of it

Comment: @BeginnerTejas: "I can't understand all of it" doesn't give me anything to go on; I don't know what you don't understand, so it is hard for me to improve the answer. **Do you have a specific question?** If you do, consider posting it; this is a question-and-answer site.

Comment: that wasn't more of a doubt. Actually you've covered so much in this particular answer viz. programming,mathematics,physics,finance etc. Was just hopping by to see what does it takes to reach that level. That's probably my question and you're right that I should post it. You don't have to reply here but people certainly need mentors like you. Thanks : )

Comment: @BeginnerTejas: I studied the design of C# for eight hours a day, five days a week, for seven years, and I had the benefit of doing so in an environment where I was the least experienced person in the room, so I had mentors to learn from. Also, I got paid to do it. If you studied a thing for 14000 hours you'd be good at it too, so if that's what you want, find a job where people pay you to learn!

Answer (score 4):

Decimal does not use an exponent to increase the range, it contains all digits (about 29), where double uses an exponent, but only contains about 19 digits, the rest is thrown away. The exponent increases the range, but not the accuracy.

Comment: This answer is correct but I want to make a clarification: `decimal` *does* use an exponent internally. It just does not use that exponent to increase the range, as double does.

Comment: @EricLippert: The exponent of `Decimal` is used to increase the range.  It doesn't increase the range nearly as far as the exponent on `Double`, but a 16-byte fixed-point type would be limited to a total of 39 decimal digits on both sides of the decimal point and `Decimal` goes beyond that, allowing allows up to 29 on the left and 28 on the right at the expense of being a floating-point type and incurring the range-based round-off errors inherent to such types.